# What is the error with this IFS condition?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to use a condition using the IFS function in Excel, but it gives me an error. Here is a simplification of the data (assume all values are in row 2) -

[image]

My condition is `=IFS(D2==1 AND F2==0, "YES",D2==0 AND F2==0, "?", D2==0 AND F2==1, "NO", D2==1 AND F2==1, "??")`

Trying this gives me an `error with the formula`. As far as I think, I have not made an error in the formula, but something is clearly wrong. I am trying to combine 4 conditions.

Any help would be wonderful.

Comment: `==` does not exist in Excel formula.  Just use `=`

Comment: Also `AND` is `AND(crit1,crit2)` not `crit1 AND crit2`

Comment: BTW: `=CHOOSE(BIN2DEC(D2&F2)+1,"?","No","Yes","??")`

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you so much!